# Different appearances despite identical CSS properties

Tags: css

I want to define a CSS class `clickable` that can be applied either to a `button` or a `div` element.  I want to make it so that *it should be impossible to tell from appearance alone* whether the underlying element is a `button.clickable` or a `div.clickable`.

For example, if one were to look at the page resulting from the following, it should be impossible to tell that the top and bottom `.clickable` elements are buttons, while the middle one is a div.

```
<div class="root">
    <button class="clickable"><span class="label">label</span></button>
    <div    class="clickable"><span class="label">label</span></div   >
    <button class="clickable"><span class="label">label</span></button>
</div>
```

It turns out that for my purposes, I require a separate child `span` to hold the label for the `.clickable` element.  Hence the `.clickable > span.label` elements shown above.

**Code snippet below (or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfe1aaqn/)):**

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.root {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    max-width: 120px;
}

.root .clickable, .root .clickable * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.root .clickable {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.root .clickable {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #eee;
  color: #111;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

.root .clickable, .root .clickable .label {
    align-items: flex-start;
    cursor: default;
    text-align: center;
}

.root .clickable {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px 6px;
}

.root .clickable .label {
    perspective-origin: 294px 7.33333349227905px;
    transform-origin: 294px 7.33333349227905px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
    <button class="clickable"><span class="label">label</span></button>
    <div    class="clickable"><span class="label">label</span></div   >
    <button class="clickable"><span class="label">label</span></button>
</div>
```

---

I have defined the CSS for `.clickable` and `.clickable .label` so that, at least when displayed under Chrome, *all* the CSS properties (including the computed/inherited/browser-assigned ones) for elements with these properties are *identical*.

*I have confirmed (using Chrome's DOM inspector) that the values for all CSS properties (including computed/inherited/browser-assigned ones) are the same for `button.clickable` and `div.clickable` elements, and for `button.clickable > .label` and `div.clickable > .label` elements.*

Nevertheless, despite their CSS properties being identical, the `button.clickable` and `div.clickable` elements look quite different:

[image]

---

- Can someone explain to me why this difference, despite the fact that the CSS properties all have identical settings?
- (less important) How should I modify the CSS for the `div.clickable` elements so that their appearance exactly matches that of the `button.clickable` elements?

---

EDIT:

The original version of this question included some invalid HTML (namely, `div` elements as children of `button` elements).  I've fixed this error, and updated the jsFiddle accordingly.

Also, the original code produced very large figures when rendered; I have modified the sizes to make the rendered results more compact.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this rules to your css:

```
.root div.clickable {
    display: table;
}
.root div.clickable .label {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/cuLuu1ps/2/

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkwuvejm/) for one possible solution

You are running into an issue because buttons get some default styling from the browser's user agent stylesheet.

Try clearing all of your CSS and just use this and you'll see what I mean (or just view this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0znoubu9/)):

```
.clickable {
    height:200px;
}
```

See how buttons automatically center text vertically by default? Your vertical-align isn't what is causing the text to be aligned vertically, that's just a browser default (which can of course be overridden).

In my attached possible solution, we center things with flex (may not be the best way to handle this depending on your needs). Specifically, I made these updates:

```
.root .clickable {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you please put the changed rules separately right after my *original* CSS settings?

Answer (score 0):

Buttons and divs have different default styling.  Buttons are more heavily styled by the browser (for example, for content to be centered by default -- and this styling can be subtly or very different between browsers).  If you want them to be identical you will need to remove the default button styling or add the associated styles to the div's class chain.

Answer (score 0):

Is because the rendering mode is distinct between `<div>` and `<button>` if you set the property `display: table-cell` , you will get the same result.

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cuLuu1ps/3/

Answer (score 0):

IMO, none of the proposed answers settle the main question of why the difference between the button and the div.  Therefore, AFAIC, this question remains open.

As to the less important question of how to get the alignment of the div's content to resemble that of the button, I found a solution that I prefer over the other ones proposed.  Just add the following:

```
.root .clickable {
    position: relative;
}

.root .clickable .label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

See the results in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0fk7o6f/).

I prefer this solution for a couple of reasons.

1. what it does is completely straightforward: position the top left corner of the content element at the center of its parent (with `top: 50%; left: 50%`), and then use `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)` to adjust the centering to account for the content's dimensions.  (I think that has less voodoo content than the average CSS fix.)
2. it does not change the `.clickable` entity's `display` property from the value explicitly given to it in the original code; (changing `display` affects the positioning of the `.clickable` element, but there was *no problem* with the positioning of the `.clickable` element in the original, and therefore it seems to me unwarranted to introduce a change that messes with it).

(In addition, I happen to have a personal bias against `flex`: support for it is not quite yet close enough to 100% for my taste, and more importantly, it seems to me like `flex` just adds yet another layer of the same design philosophy that gave us the practically undebuggable nightmare that is CSS; IOW, `flex` is just a whole new bunch of properties and values to interact in unpredictable ways with everything else, and to increase the already insanely large "surface area" that one needs to cover when debugging this stuff.  I think I'll pass on that.  Then again, even if I liked `flex` a lot more than I do, I still would avoid it for this problem, for the reason explained in (2) above.)